# using libusb with embeded system linux based

Tags: linux, yocto, libusb, libusb-1.0, intel-edison

i'm using libusb in intel edison board
lsusb command shows the usb device but when i try to run the code I get this error:

```
root@admin:/root# ./out
Error finding USB device
```

here is lsusb command output:

```
root@admin:/root# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0483:3748 STMicroelectronics ST-LINK/V2
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

i'm using [this example](https://github.com/libusb/libusb/blob/master/examples/listdevs.c)

Do you have any idea?

Comment: I tried on my laptop and everything works, even without `sudo`. How are you compiling it? Which library are you linking?

Comment: here is my compile command:
gcc -L /usr/local/lib usbcode.c -o usbcode -lusb-1.0
i had no compile errors

Comment: then try `./usbcode` instead of `./out`

Comment: i compiled with different names, out and usbcode. both of them had same error

Comment: Maybe you should try the http://communities.intel.com, there are some posts on `libsub` there. It seems a lot of people are struggling with usb in the intel edison board.

Comment: @Rogus, it works for me, though I'm not using official BSP at all.